# Where does the period go in an MLA in-text citation?

Tags: punctuation, quotes, periods

I've always been confused when citing like:

> "The windows misted over from the heat and the smoke inside.” (Hemingway 1)

Does the period go inside the quotes (as above)? Or after the citation (as below)?

> "The windows misted over from the heat and the smoke inside” (Hemingway 1).

Comment: I suggest you check out [EasyBib.com](http://www.easybib.com/). I used it extensively when I was in school and it is super handy. You can either give it a URL, ISBN #, or just fill in the relevant details in a form and it will automatically generate a properly formatted citation in a number of different styles, including MLA.

Comment: I also found that using a program like Zotero was a very effective way to organize my sources. Once you download the plugin or standalone, and you get the extension for your browser, you can download the data you need for your citation by using a little link in the corner of your browser. You can then choose a source and create a citation or a bibliography (from a number of sources) and paste it into your essay. It works with many types of citation styles such as MLA, Chicago, and AAA, among others.

Comment: This may be more appropriate on [writers.se]

Comment: Migrate to academia.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @AE Punctuation and style guide info is very much on topic here at ELU.

Comment: What is MLA? Medical Licensing Association does not seem relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The second is correct, the period [goes after](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/) the citation. For example:

> (Rowling 8).

Answer (score 2):

"The period goes after the complete citation because the citation is considered part of the sentence" (me 34).

Answer (score -2):

The period goes at the end of the whole sentence, including the page number, otherwise you would be giving the page number its own sentence.   :/

Comment: Welcome to the site, ajit - generally, if the question already has an accepted answer, there is no point giving the same answer. Instead, why not upvote the existing answer?

Comment: "Instead, why not upvote the existing answer?" --- Because ajit's hoping to get some reputation out of this answer. (Not saying it is okay to do so...)